# How to remove HTML tags from strings?

Tags: php, string, html-parsing

I am looking to remove a chunk out of a string dynamically, from the occurrence of one character `<` to the occurrence of another set of 2 characters `/>`. Here's an example of what might be output:

```
<img src='blah.png' width="300" height="225" />There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slight...
```

It might not be an `img` tag, it could be an `img` inside an anchor tag, or no tags at all. What I'm after is the string after the tags (if any), more specifically the first 50 words. But I have the stripping down to 50 words thing working, i just need the tags ripped out. And I can't cheat and use `img {display:none;}` as the characters are counted.

Is this possible using PHP?

Comment: Did you try `strip_tags`? http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I was looking at `strip_tags` but there might be text inside of a tag like an anchor tag, that I don't want in there. Thanx for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$string = "<img src='blah.png' width="300" height="225" />There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slight...";
$new_string = preg_replace('/<.*?\/>/','',$string);
```

Still, if you're just parsing html tags, may regexp wouldn't be the best way to go. But if it's just removing some strings, then it may help.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid regexp, but it may be my only solution. Thanx for your input.

Comment: Tags don't usually end with `/>` (some do, sometimes, but you probably can't count on that). @MattRyan Regex is great. Why not use it? It's great!

Comment: @Rudie, I just answered what OP asked D:, and yeah, about regex, totally agree

Comment: He asked about self closing tags only? I missed that. Still don't see it, but I believe you. #regex4ever!

Comment: You are right, tags these days, are not supposed to be self closing anymore(since HTML5). At least i think that's the term. Most CMS' still use them though, as far as I know anyways. I typically use regexp for things like testing email addresses and such, when it comes to HTML tags and a user creating them, regexp is not 100% reliable.